# How to Inherit/Apply Wordpress Template CSS Image Handling to my Widget

Tags: css, wordpress

My Wordpress template, by default pads images and puts a border around them, dimming the padding when you mouse over to show it's a link.

I have developed a custom plugin/widget and want the same effect for its images. I suppose I can recreate styling in the Widget CSS file. But I was hoping I could somehow call on the whole default styling from the template CSS.

Is this possible... if so what might it look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this two functions in yours plugin/widget. This is native functions to enque style into wordpress.

```
wp_register_style( 'style_name', '../../style_url', false, '1.0', 'all' );     
wp_enqueue_style( 'style_name' );
```

Last 3 arguments wp_register_style are optional.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Which file sorry? I assume this is not CSS.

Comment: @square_eyes, As I understood correctly, You want to make custom css for widget and register it ? If so in functions.php you should paste this code in function widget() block.

Comment: OK thanks, and then I update style_name and CSS url? I don't have a fuctions.php should I add one in the plugin folder?

Comment: You should paste them where You registering widget for wordpress. Usualy it in functions.php file. In my situation it was like wp_register_style( 'shortcodes', plugin_url() . '/css/style.css', false, '1.0', 'all' );wp_enqueue_style( 'shortcodes' );

Comment: OK I found that. My widget.php contains `<?php register_widget( $widget_class ) ?>` but when I add the code above it takes down my whole site.